# How can I use sequelize raw query nest option with nested queries?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have the next nested query:

```
const myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT id AS "tableAlias.id" FROM table AS tableAlias) AS records';

const records = sequelize.query(myQuery, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT, nest: true, raw: true, plain: true });

console.log(records); 

// { records: [{ "tableAlias.id": 1 }] }
```

This, or something similar, works, but the output that I want is:

```
// { records: [{ tableAlias: { id: 1 } }] }
```

Like the typical object structure.

`nest: true` seems to work for simple queries, but not for my nested query.

If you wanna know why I have a nested query in my original query, it is because a need an `UNION ALL` statement and Sequelize does not support it the way I need.

More info about the query structure:

```
WITH (/*here I do my nested query with UNION ALL */) AS nestedQueryResult

SELECT (
(SELECT MIN(dates) FROM nestedQueryResult) AS minDate, 
(SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM nestedQueryResult AS t) AS results, 
(SELECT COUNT(nestedQueryResult) FROM nestedQueryResult) AS count)
as myResults;
```

**More info:**

I have been debugging the query step by step and nest does not work when I use the `json_agg` function on the query result.

```
return `SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM (${queries}) as t`;
```